# При добавлении объекта в массив он заменятся

Tags: javascript

```
let orders = []; // массив заказов
let orderData = {
  id: "",
  title: "",
  size: "",
  weight: "",
  ingridients: [],
  price: "",
  total_price: null,
  quantity: 0,
}; // болванка объекта заказа
let order = {}; // костыль чтоб избавиться от ссылки
let storageOrdersData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("orders", orders)); // получаю массив заказов из хранилища

// проверяю есть ли уже сохраненные в хранилище заказы
if (storageOrdersData !== null) {
 const foundedItem = storageOrdersData.find((item) => item.id === orderData.id); //ищу совпадения
 // если есть...
 if (foundedItem) {
   foundedItem.quantity++; // увеличиваю количество товара(заказа)
   foundedItem.total_price = foundedItem.quantity * foundedItem.price; // увеличиваю стоимость
   orders.push(foundedItem); // пушу в массив
 } else {
   order = {
     id: orderData.id,
     title: orderData.title,
     size: orderData.size,
     weight: orderData.weight,
     ingridients: orderData.ingridients,
     price: orderData.price,
     total_price: orderData.prtotal_priceice,
     quantity: orderData.quantity,
   }; // заполняю костыль чтоб наверняка объекты были разные
   orders.push(order); // пушу
 }
}

localStorage.setItem("orders", JSON.stringify(orders)); // записываю в хранилище
```

Получается что при добавлении уже имеющегося заказа количество и цена пересчитываются, но если такого заказа нет..то вместо пуша нового заменятся сохраненный ранее...

Comment: зачем вам два массива для списка заказов?

Comment: почему два? вроде только orders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`let orders = []` -  вы каждый раз создаете новый массив. Затем пушите в него один элемент. Наверное, вы хотите объединить новые данные с сохраненными?

```
let storageOrdersData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("orders", orders));
let orders = storageOrdersData || []
```

Comment: Ну точно...глаз заплыл...благодарю